How to Replace the expression with unknown parameters？
I do not want to do Derivative, because it will be very slow after million times.
My expression is just the Exponential as following,
s = t*E^(p (a*x + b*y + c*z));
tt0=D[s, {x, 2}]
tt1=s /. {E^(p (a*x + b*y + c*z)) -> p^2 a^2 E^(p (a*x + b*y + c*z))}

However, tt1 works only if all the parameters are known. If I do no know the parameters p,a,b,c, is there any way to get tt1?
My expression are millions of Exponential, I only write two as examples,
s = 0.5*E^(I*0.7*(0.2 x + 0.3 y + 0.4 z)) + 0.9*E^(I*0.3*(0.1 x + 0.2 y + 0.3 z));
tt0=D[s, {x, 2}] // Simplify

How to get tt1 by Replace?

do you mean all your derivatives are of second order, and the expressions are all of the form  $e^{f(x,\dots)}$ ?  If so, how about e = E^(p (a*x + b*y + c*z)); tt1 = s /. Exp[any_] :> D[any, x]^2*Exp[any]  I can't imagine that taking derivative of polynomial in $x$ will be that slow in Mathematica, even for millions of them.

For your second example, same thing. But you can generalize it as follows tt1 = s /. a_. Exp[b_] :> a*D[b, x]^2*Exp[b];  see if this works for you.  https://i.sstatic.net/oTe5GeYA.png

Thank you so much! But in your code, you still do Derivative: D[b, x]. Is it possible to avoid the D[b, x]?

Yes, it is possible. But are all arguments of Exp  linear polynomial in $x$?

Yes, all the arguments of Exp are in direct proportion to x,y,z

Ok, try this and see if this works for you tt1 = s /.  a_. Exp[b_] :> a*Select[Expand[b], Not[FreeQ[#, x]] &]^2*Exp[b]; Simplify[tt1]  No derivatives involved.  This just selects the part with $x$ from the argument of the exponential.

Thank you! But the output seems add the x^2

I add [[1]]，so that the output do not involve x^2. tt1 = s /.
a_. Exp[b_] :> aSelect[Expand[b], Not[FreeQ[#, x]] &][[1]]^2Exp[b]

Try this simpler version and see tt1 = s /. a_. Exp[b_] :> a*Coefficient[Expand[b], x]^2*Exp[b]; Simplify[tt1]  This uses the command Coefficient to get the coefficient of the linear term of $x$

Great! It maybe faster after million times! Thank you again!

I test the speed and precision of two codes (with D[] and without D[]) in my program. Both codes are faster than the original code tt0. The fastest code is tt1a=a_. Exp[b_] :> aD[b, x]^2Exp[b], two times faster than aCoefficient tt1b=[Expand[b], x]^2Exp[b], but they have completely the same precision (In MMA, tt1a-tt1b shows 0.0+0.0i, while the result of tt0-tt1a or tt0-tt1b is the number 10^-16, but not 0.0+0.0i). So I will choose tt1a in my code.

So I have another question, could I know the RAW information of D[]?Maybe I will speed up the code again.

could I know the RAW information of D[]? sorry, I do not know what this means.

I hope to know each step of D[] in MMA. Take NIntegrate as example,  I could set the Method (i.e."LocalAdaptive" or "QuasiMonteCarlo") to speed up the NIntegrate, if I know the integrand. Could I set the method or strategy to speedup D[]? I already know the function.

good question but I am not sure I know the answer now. You could try to make new question on the site and see if someone knows better.
